# Xamarin Forms Game Development

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to Game Development. However, have been using Xamarin and Xamarin.Forms for quite a while now.

I am trying to build a game (for Android and iOS) which will have many screens, one of which will have a view like Clash Of Clans in game view (i.e. the attack view). I am guessing it will like Isometric Projection (https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-isometric-worlds-a-primer-for-game-developers--gamedev-6511). I know that I can build most of the gaming screen like Play Game, View account and so on using Xamarin Forms.

What I would like to know is, is it possible to build the isometric projection view using Xamarin.Forms and if so is it ideal to build it in Forms (like using Tiled with Cocosharp OR maybe using Unity or URHO)?

Ideally, we would like to have one code base and hence we are going for Xamarin.Forms . But I am not sure if it will provide the best outcome compared to building it seperatly for Android and iOS.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: About your last question if Xamarin is good for this project: It depends how complex the project is. Xamarin is generally intended for simple projects. You might find yourself coding many custom renderers if you have complex views etc.

Comment: I'd go with Unity - it's also C# and it's made for creating multiplatform games. Xamarin Forms is generally recommended for simple applications with rather simple views. You could use pure Xamarin and write separate views for both platforms, but in my opinion it's pointless - it's better to create one set of custom UIs in Unity. Also there will be no overhead in using things like isometric perspective, it's all there in Unity.

Comment: Thank you guys. Is there a way to use Unity with Xamarin or Xamarin Forms or you talking about using only Unity?

Comment: I do not believe Xamarin.Forms is a good choice for a game with a lot of animation. You may want to look at monogame which is still cross platform but intended to fill this need. http://www.monogame.net/

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/graphics-games/game-development/

Comment: @Thameem that is the best link I could find today. Thank you very much

Comment: @Gian Gomen I am glad it helped someone..

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use Unity3D the only solution to use it within Xamarin.Forms would be to create a BrowserGame with Unity3D and then call it from a webview. But if you are new to Game Development as you said, maybe CocosSharp is the way to go. You can add it as a NuGet to your existing Xamarin.Forms app. There is also a neat official Xamarin.Forms Tutorial: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/cocossharp/

Answer (score 0):

As @Thameem stated in his comment this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/graphics-games/game-development/ explain how to integrate games in xamarin apps. Also provides several links for further searching in the option you choose.